# Excel how to format a cell

Tags: excel, format

```
SER_T_L1 04-06-2018 8:00-04-06-2018 12:00
SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:00-05-06-2018 16:30 
SER_Behandeling 05-06-2018 9:30-05-06-2018 18:00 
SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:30-05-06-2018 16:00 
SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:30-05-06-2018 17:00
```

Above are examples. What I would need is it to only show the the two times. So for example above would look like:

```
08:00 - 12:00
08:00 - 16:30
09:30 - 18:00
08:30 - 16:00
08:30 - 17:00
```

Comment: Are they always in this pattern shown? I am not sure formatting alone will produce the desired result.

Comment: No these are more examples: 
SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:00-05-06-2018 16:30 

SER_Behandeling 05-06-2018 9:30-05-06-2018 18:00

SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:30-05-06-2018 16:00 

SER_T_L1 05-06-2018 8:30-05-06-2018 17:00

Comment: I suggest you edit your post to show a number of your samples, commenting is not a very good way to expand your sample data.

Comment: Good suggestion @HakanERDOGAN thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is in A1, use the following formula (assuming you never have colons in your "SER" label):

`=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)-2,5))&" - "&TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1)-2,5))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first row is at `A1`, write below formula to `B1` and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)-2,5)) & " - " & TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1,1)+1)-2,5))
```

Formula consists of two `MID` functions, taking the location of first and second ":" characters since they are the delimiters for time portions.

If your data contains ":" characters in other parts than the times, then we should be thinking of another way to do this, probably rip off the first part before the blank and get the time data from remaining string.

Comment: THANKK YOU SO MUCH! Also thanks for adding explanation